# Definition of "Number"

Tags: meaning

Is there a definition in English for "Number" to mean a sequence of 1 or more of (digits/numerics, alphabetical letters, symbols, and/or spaces).
Ex:

- 134432A
- 134432-A
- 134432.A
- 134432 A

Comment: Perhaps [**alphanumeric**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/alphanumeric) or just [**code**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/code).

Comment: It's a piece of music played in a theatrical performance.  It refers to a slightly crazy person.

Comment: I doubt there is a single term, you probably need to use a lengthy description, such as [alphanumeric invoice number](https://debitoor.com/blog/new-custom-number-series)

Comment: Note that 'DEADBEEF' is a perfectly legitimate number ... in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, ish.**

As BoldBen commented, the [**UK National Insurance Number**](https://www.gov.uk/apply-national-insurance-number) is formatted AA 99 99 99 A (where A is letter and 9 is a decimal number).

There's also the **Driver Number** or [Driving licence number](https://www.gov.uk/view-driving-licence) on driving licences, format AAAAA 999999 AXXAA (where X is either a letter or the digit 9 as a space-filler).

There's an internationally-defined **Vehicle Identification Number** on vehicles, which contains letters and digits.

And the *registration number* of vehicles which displayed on their *number plate* consists of letters and digits.

*Telephone numbers* used to contain letters as well as digits. *Serial numbers* on equipment commonly contain letters as well as digits.

All of these are called numbers. However, all of them are qualified: "National Insurance" number; "Driver" number; "Vehicle Identification" Number; "registration" number; "telephone" number; "serial" number.

Dictionary definitions all refer to even serial numbers as numbers.

So: while a number needs to consist of digits, you can **qualify** a number for a particular purpose and **that** number (or what is called a number) might contain letters as well.

Comment: Telephone numbers are somewhat different from the other examples given here, because the letters in them were only mnemonic tools; it was always possible to state them accurately with numerals only. The letters in the other kinds of numbers are, however, ineliminable.

Comment: Even house numbers sometimes include letters- 221B Baker St.

Answer (score 1):

#### The term 'Number' is widely used sloppily for identifiers that can contain letters too

People have given you examples above, including:

- Passport numbers of some countries e.g. Germany (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_passport)
  [image]
- Car Number Plates
- UK National Insurance Numbers
- Equipment Serial Numbers

This is now so widespread that we should probably now accept it as part of the language, and not argue with it.

#### 'Alphanumeric' is not quite right

It satisfactorily describes the German passport "number", but not the codes you provided, where you (I assume) wanted all of these valid codes to be *distinct*.

```
134432A
134432-A
134432.A
134432 A
```

To take the extra effort to call your format an "alphanumeric" code, would be a shame, since a technically minded person (such as a person planning to store the data in a computer) might not allow for non-alpha, non-numeric symbols.

#### 'Code' or 'Identifier'

These would be the simplest and yet accurate terms for what you want. If you think "Code" might sound too mysterious to normal people, "Identifier" should be more reassuring. People are already familiar with "ID" as a document of identification of a person, and would readily map that understanding to an "ID" being a unique text identifier of a thing.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a definition of 'number' which permits the inclusion of letters might look strange. One option is to simply to use the word 'series' without specifying the categories in the series.

The word can be used as follows:

> The **series** 134432A contains a hidden message.

Having said that, there seems to be a variety of instances where the inclusion of non-numbers is acceptable. People use the term 'registration number' for a car (it often has letters), although I think the correct term is "registration plate". Your suggestion of an invoice number is a good example of where the inclusion of a letter might be possible. In other words, sometimes for convenience, the word 'number' is used even if a letter is included. However, I think that this usage might not be part of official definitions.

Comment: Ever seen the term "Invoice Number"?

Comment: That's a very valid point! I'll edit my answer to include some examples.

Comment: In the UK most people have a National Insurance identifier which is allocated when they start work and pay the National Insurance contribution for the first time. This is referred to universally, including by the National Insurance authorities, the Income Tax department and many other government bodies, as the National Insurance Number. However its format is AA 99 99 99 A (where A is letter and 9 is a decimal number)

Comment: @BoldBen I agree that those are definitely valid examples, but those are contextual definitions, i.e. a specific organization defining a series which contains alphanumeric characters as "a ... number". I'm not sure that is the same thing as a specific definition of the word 'number' as permitting letters. I think the OP means 'definition of number'.

Comment: @BoldBen - Brits call it the NINO, but Americans who come to live in the UK often don't get that, and write "NiN" or something like that, in forums.

Comment: Surely you mean sequence, not series.

Comment: What would make a definition of an ordinary English word **official**?

Comment: @jsw29 Putting it in bold. 8-)

Comment: @tchrist No, I don't mean sequence because sequence implies an ordering rule of some sort, whereas series does not.

Comment: @kandyman So 134432A is the same as 41A2334, A314342, 3A24413, etc? Good to know.

Comment: Save your sarcastic attitude for somewhere else. It’s not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Digits compose numerals, which represent numbers.  Eg, a hundred and one dots is the number of (non-gathered) dots represented by the numeral 101, with digits, 1, 0, and 1.

Possibly, the word alphanumeric came to be to describe stuff like alphanumeric problems, etc, which involve substituting numerical values for strings or sequences of letters, etc, with different digits for different letters.

I would call these things strings or sequences of characters containing such and such.  Character string.  Beyond this, a series is the sum, or product, etc, of a sequence of terms.